# Running an Azure Pipeline Gradle task locally

Tags: gradle, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to debug a Gradle task in an Azure Pipeline by running it locally. The YAML definition of the task is:

```
- task: Gradle@2
  displayName: 'Test Project'
  inputs:
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx7000m'
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: true
    sonarQubeGradlePluginVersion: 2.6.2
    testRunTitle: $(DISPLAY_NAME)
    codeCoverageToolOption: JaCoCo
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/build/test-results/test/TEST-*.xml'
    tasks: "test -Dtest.profile=unit --parallel"
```

I'm trying to figure out the equivalent local command. I've got as far as

```
./gradlew test -DcodeCoverageToolOption=JaCoCo -Dtest.profile=unit --parallel
```

However, I'm not sure how to pass the other arguments, e.g. `codeCoverageToolOption: JaCoCo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.codeCoverageToolOption: JaCoCo**

For Azure Devops, `codeCoverageToolOption: JaCoCo` means choose a code coverage tool `JaCoCo` to determine the code that is covered by the test cases. But, there's no such command for gradle to **choose** which code coverage tool would to use.

In gradle, the similar operations is add `JaCoCo` plugin as `dependencies` in `build.gradle` firstly. Now, you could be able to call `jacocoTestReport` task to create a code coverage report.

```
./gradlew test jacocoTestReport
```

***Note***: The `jacocoTestReport` task will do nothing if the `test.exec` file does not exist. So, you should always run the `test` or `build` task first

---

**2. testResultsFiles**

For `testResultsFiles` in YAML, it use to specify the test results files should put in. But, for gradle, its default path is `build/reports/jacoco/test/html/index.html` which be specified in your `build.gradle` file. Simple sample:

```
task codeCoverageReport(type: JacocoReport) {
    executionData fileTree(project.rootDir.absolutePath).include("**/build/jacoco/*.exec")
    subprojects.each {
        sourceSets it.sourceSets.main
    }
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        xml.destination "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/{TestResultFileName}.xml"
        html.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
    }
}
```

---

**3. publishJUnitResults: true**

In azure devops, we does not publish the Test result file into VSTS with gradle command. What we use to achieve this is with script: [CodeCoverage Publish](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/76200ad1d7f16dfbdcc0a72edcf472068ba3a820/Tasks/PublishTestResultsV2/publishtestresults.ts#L17).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have a follow-up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58398359/generating-code-coverage-reports-on-azure-devops-with-gradle-5-x

Comment: @AntonioDragos, Aha, welcome. Will have a look at it:-)